# The meaning of " haut to trot"?

Tags: meaning, expressions

What's the meaning of this expression " Modelling : She's haut to trot !"

Comment: "Hot to trot" is a slightly off-color expression meaning someone (generally female) who is relatively anxious/willing to have sexual relations.  "Haut to trot" is a play on those words, playing on the term "haute couture" which refers to the industry supplying very exclusive/expensive clothes.  Presumably the individual is doing really well in that business.  (The clothing business, that is, not the other one.)

Comment: Or she's wearing haute couture, AND "hot to trot"!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In its most general sense *[Hot to trot:](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hot-to-trot?q=hot%20to%20trot)*

> informal
>
> Ready and eager to engage in an activity.
>
> OED

More [specifically](http://idioms.thefreedictionary.com/hot+to+trot) an alternate definition of [hot](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/hot) implies a [double entendre](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/double-entendre?q=double%20entendre):

> Sexually avid, lascivious.
>
> Both slangy usages allude to a horse eager to get going.
>
> The American Heritage® Dictionary of Idioms

Substituting *haute* for *hot* evokes the expression [*haute couture*](http://www.oxforddictionaries.com/definition/english/haute-couture?q=haute%20couture):

> NOUN
>
> [MASS NOUN]
>
> 1.0 Expensive, fashionable clothes produced by leading fashion houses:
>
> Origin: French, literally 'high dressmaking'.

Because our English word *[haughty](http://www.etymonline.com/index.php?allowed_in_frame=0&search=haughty&searchmode=none)* comes from the French *haute*, some imply the double entendre becomes a quadruple entendre. She's:

> - eager to show off her clothes?
> - eager to show off her modeling skills?
> - eager to show off her body?
> - eager to show off her sexual power?

In reality, it is a popular expression for [high end marketing](https://www.google.com/search?q=haut%20to%20trot&es_sm=119&biw=1291&bih=738&nfpr=1&source=lnms&sa=X&ei=KYDUVMvaFMOeNsbcgtgP&ved=0CAUQ_AUoAA&dpr=1#q=haute%20to%20trot) to women.

---

Perhaps the "misspelling" of [haut](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/Haut) is a German's attempt to knock her down a notch?

> German
>
> Haut f
>
> 1. skin, hide of a person, animal or (part of a) plant
> 2. (pars pro toto) the creature itself, notably a person in brave Haut
>      'good-natured hide'
> 3. similar membrane ('skin') on the surface of an object, such as a
>      sausage

Answer (score 3):

I found this paragraph in an article while researching family history.

> After 1000 A.D., border life was in turmoil. In 1246, 6 Chiefs from the Scottish side and 6 from the English side met at Carlisle and produced a set of laws governing all the border Clans. These were unlike any laws prevailing in England or Scotland or, for that matter, anywhere else in the world. For example, it was a far greater offence to refuse to help a neighbour recover his property, wife, sheep, cattle or horses than it was to steal them in the first place. Hence the expression "**Hot Trod**", or, a hot pursuit, from which we get the modern **"Hot to trot"**. For refusal of assistance during a "Hot Trod", a person could be hanged on the instant, without trial. Frequently, the descendants of these clans or families apologetically refer to themselves as being descended from "Cattle or horse thieves" when, in fact, it was an accepted code of life on the border.

Source: [Origins of the Bellingham surname](http://bellinghamroot.tripod.com/bellingh/surname.htm)

Comment: This would benefit from some references to support the origin of the term.

Comment: This would benefit from some evidence that anyone ever used the phrase *hot trod* before someone decided it was the source of another phrase.

Comment: This would benefit from an answer to the question: What does “She’s haut to trot!” (or “hot to trot”) mean? And … seriously? … this joke gets more votes than the accepted answer, which gives a correct, contemporary definition of “hot to trot” ***and*** explains that, in the given context, it’s a pun?  Are we upvoting absurdity for absurdity’s sake now?